# Displaying axis values in hexadecimal in R

Tags: r

How do I go about displaying an axis in hexadecimal in R, in a scatter plot? The data I am reading in from the `CSV` is already in hexadecimal.

I'm trying to display memory accesses, and here is my current code:

```
vec <- read.csv("http://example.com/example.csv")
y <- vec$high
x <- vec$low

plot(x, y, main="Memory Accesses", 
     xlab="Low 32-bits ", ylab="High 32-bits ", pch=19, cex=0.1)
```

Which displays:

[image: scatter plot for memory accesses]

Comment: using `as.hexmode`? `axis(3, 0:6 * 10000, as.hexmode(0:6 * 10000))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by rawr while I was writing this answer (note that `0:6 * 10000` is nicer that what I wrote, but don't want to steal it):

```
plot(x, y, main="Memory Accesses", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     xlab="Low 32-bits ", ylab="High 32-bits ", pch=19, cex=0.1)
axis(1, seq(0,60000,10000), paste0("0x",as.hexmode(seq(0,60000,10000))))
axis(2, seq(0,60000,10000), paste0("0x",as.hexmode(seq(0,60000,10000))))
```

[image]